# Add 'usa' tag to 'collegescorecard' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since the *college score card* is a US Department of Education measure it is tempting to add the [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) tag to question having the [scorecard](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scorecard) tag. I have done so a few times already.

But since this is a typical US invention, that may be superflous.

Do we add the [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) tag or not?

Answer (score 3):

No, do not add the [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) tag. Instead, make sure that the [tag wiki](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/collegescorecard/info) makes clear that it is a US invention.